# Python/Pandas - My code is working but does not do the job

Tags: python, ruby, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working on a cucumber feature written in Ruby; for this particular step I used a snipped of python, more exactly Pandas. What I am trying to achieve:

1. Read an Excel file
2. Delete the empty rows, delete the header (1st row) and the index (1st column)
3. Save the file in csv format.
   This is the code that I used:

```
require 'pandas'
Then(/^I delete the empty rows using python code$/) do
  df = Pandas.read_excel('C:/Downloads/WAG12895/Report.xls')
  engine='python'

  new_df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
  new_df.to_csv('C:/Downloads/WAG12895/Report.csv',  sep=',', header=false, index=false)

end
```

**
Tag: @@excelfeature
1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)
0m5.682s
**

My code works but is Not removing the header and the index no matter what - only the empty lines.
I've tried also drop() and iloc([1:]), but nothing.

More than that, I've tried the code in pure python in a different IDE (atom) and there it works perfectly, but since this is a step from a bigger project I need to convert it or find a solution in ruby.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('Report.xls')
new_df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
new_df.to_csv("Report.csv", header=None, index=False)
```

**I am looking for some suggestions or a workaround to solve this.**
Thank you in advance!

Comment: because false is not equal to False

Comment: @ChristianSloper In ruby there is only 'false', but I've tried also 'False' and I got this:
```
NameError: uninitialized constant False
Did you mean?  FALSE
```
Tried also FALSE and this is deprecated.

Comment: in python there is only False , unless you have a variable named false, in which case we will have a talk about your variable naming.

Comment: I don't have a variable named false and I know that False is in python, but true, false, and nil are special built-in data types in Ruby. The weird part is that I can use pandas inside ruby through a gem and it works (almost) as it should exempt the header and index and fileformat from what I noticed. Still looking for an alternative on how to remove the header and the index - I believe this is possible with win32OLE, but just thinking aloud. Python is my priority for the moment.

Comment: just saying that this: " new_df.to_csv('C:/Downloads/WAG12895/Report.csv',  sep=',', header=false, index=false)" isn't valid python code.

false probably is evaluating to true here

Comment: in this (the working example): "new_df.to_csv("Report.csv", header=None, index=False)"   you are using False correctly.

Comment: I finally fixed my code; apparently, all I needed to do is to replace "=" with ":" :
```
 new_df.to_csv('Report.csv', sep=',', header: false, index: false)
```